# Good ways to Learn Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa

I'd love to learn Cocoa, it seems like the best systems language for Mac OS X.

Can you recommend any useful ways to learn the language?  Books, websites, example projects or even classes to take?

Comment: Note that Cocoa isn't a language. Cocoa is the "best systems" framework for Mac OS X. And Objective-C is probably the language you want to learn to use it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Andy Matuschak has a great [blog post](http://andymatuschak.org/articles/2007/09/09/getting-started-with-cocoa-a-friendlier-approach/) that leads you through several good Cocoa tutorials, explaining why you are reading each one.

[Cocoa Dev Central](http://www.cocoadevcentral.com/) has loads of tutorials.

For books, I echo Dave and Phillip Bowden with [Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X by Aaron Hillegass](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503619).

Comment: The link to Andy's blog post is dead. [This is the copy of the article at web archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20080916184841/http://andymatuschak.org/articles/2007/09/09/getting-started-with-cocoa-a-friendlier-approach/).

Answer (score 8):

Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X, by Aaron Hillegass.

Answer (score 6):

1. Read and follow the [Become an Xcoder](http://www.cocoalab.com/?q=becomeanxcoder) tutorial.
2. Read [Cocoa Programming for the Mac OS X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00139XSRO) and type in all the code.
3. You can also watch [CocoaCast](http://www.cocoacast.com/) if you would like to watch how programming is done instead of just reading it.
4. The Cocoa documentation in apple's developer website is also a very good resource. Work your way on the Cocoa and Objective-C conceptual guides and work out the samples.
5. Finally, just practice and apply what you've read/seen on your own application.

Answer (score 4):

[Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503619) is a great book that covers Objective-C and many of the frameworks that make up Cocoa. Most Cocoa programmers I know learned from this book (including myself). The third edition was released recently, so it's fairly up to date. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to check out http://www.cocoalab.com/?q=becomeanxcoder. It goes from the very fundamentals of programming to learning Cocoa, Xcode and more.

Answer (score 1):

[Big Nerd Ranch](http://www.bignerdranch.com/classes/cocoa.shtml) The definitive class to take...well worth it!

Comment: Hello @epatel I've been developing iOS since couple of years,Now I'd like start develop apps for OS X,Could you help me out?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Buy a book, open XCode, and *write*. Seriously, writing is *the best way* to learn Cocoa. In addition, I recommend [Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321213149)!

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on learning Cocoa myself recently and have found Apple's own [Cocoa resources](http://developer.apple.com/cocoa/) to be incredibly helpful.

For example projects I have spent quite a bit of time in the [Adium source](http://trac.adiumx.com/wiki/GettingAdiumSource).  Adium is a relatively large project so I am very often able to find examples of whichever concept I am interested in.

The [CocoaDev](http://www.cocoadev.com/) wiki can also be quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best books I read about Cocoa is [Cocoa (Developer Reference)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470495898) by Richard Wentk

Answer (score 0):

Best books I encountered are those from Apress, in this case : Beginning iPhone 4 Development. Was much clearer to me than those from O'Reilly