# Any suggestions for iPhone development resources?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, resources

I need to do some coding on iPhone and I am new to this field. A good forum or tutorial will be of great help. So I am here for some best iPhone resources, can some one help?

Thanks in advance ~
(If you have any experiences of developing on iPhone and you'd like to share with us, please do not hesitate:)

Comment: Try a search before asking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find your local CocoaHeads group:  http://cocoaheads.org

Our group has compiled a pretty large collection of resources: http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/resources (there are currently 62 items tagged in the "iphone" category)

Beyond this, there are a lot of other great links that have been posted before:

[Good ways to Learn Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67875)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571

[Good resources for learning Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374660)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130863

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461426

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353130

Not all of them are exactly centered on "iPhone development", but since both Mac and iPhone are Objective-C and Cocoa, what's applicable to one is usually applicable to the other.

Comment: @Dave, thanks for your prompt reply. I will check out them soon!