# How to get started with Cocoa application development?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm a Java guy who is familiar with Swing programming and recently just started out with iPhone programming. Boy the learning curve was steep and now I would like to start Cocoa development for desktop apps.

I've been reading on articles and considering buying few cocoa book to advance my learning, still I feel I don't fully get it yet. I started about 3 months back and pretty comfortable with XCode and Objective-C but developing cocoa for desktop apps looks like a different game from iPhone development.

My questions are:

1. Suitable book to pick up and learn from.
2. What blogs I should follow?
3. Any code example I should look at to learn from.

I've been looking at Adium src and considering buying Cocoa Programming 3rd but the book looks like bunch of stuff I already kinda know.

Comment: Looks like http://www.cocoadev.com got most of my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Suitable book to pick up and learn from.

- [Aaron Hillegass - Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503619)

> What blogs I should follow?

- [Scott Stevenson](http://theocacao.com/)
- [Wil Shipley](http://www.wilshipley.com/blog)
- [Cocoa is my girlfriend](http://www.cimgf.com/)

> Any code example I should look at to learn from.

- [Apple's Currency Converter tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCTutorial/01Introduction/01Introduction.html)
- [Apple's Currency Converter tutorial with cocoa bindings](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CurrencyConverterBindings/01introduction/introduction.html)

**EDIT:** There is already a comprehensive list here on SO:
[Good ways to Learn Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67875/good-ways-to-learn-cocoa)

Comment: Have to agree - the Hillegass tome is most definitely worth a read, although the OP will probably already have a good feel of things from cutting his teeth on the iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Our CocoaHeads group has a really large list of resources:

http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/resources

If you're looking for books, check out:  http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/resources/book

Or blogs: http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/resources/blog

Or tutorials: http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/resources/tutorial

Or sample code: http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/resources/sample-code

etc